# How to populate the Active choice Parameter dropdown list in Jenkins using a JSON file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use Active Choice Parameter Choice Parameter to populate the dropdown list from JSON values.
However when I use the Build with Parameters its blank. I want to populate the FullName value in the dropdown list.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVdEM.png)

cust.json :

```
[ {
    "fullName": "Company Inc.",
    "shortName": "comp",
    "salesforceID": "0000",
    "jpower": "00000"
},{
    "fullName": "Company 1 Inc.",
    "shortName": "comp1",
    "salesforceID": "0001",
    "jpower": "00001"
}]
```

My Groovy script :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def file_data= new File('/home/jenkins/readJson/ds-github-utils/conf/customers.json').text
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurperClassic()
def data = jsonParser().parseText(file_data)
return fullName
```

Comment: Have you tried `.getText()` instead of `.text` on your file()_?

Comment: Yes tried it nothing is loaded in Build Parameters Customer name its blank

Comment: As you haven't allocated a `node` yet (allocation impossible before getting to the `pipeline` stage, which only happens after the parameters are filled), it's unclear where your code is running or whether the file is actually there.

Comment: I have the file on the Jenkins Master. I thought that after one build the Jenkins will populate the parameter. I have this script under the Active choice parameter Groovy section. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has two errors, the is not method `()` on defined `jsonParser` object so the line: `def data = jsonParser().parseText(file_data)`, must be: `def data = jsonParser.parseText(file_data)`.

The second problem is that `fullname` is not a variable and is not defined in the context, if you want to access the json `fullname` value, you must use parsed object in `data` variable : `return data.fullName`.

All together (I put the json inside the script only to testing purposes but you can read from your file as you do in your script):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def filedata = 
''' 
[ {
    "fullName": "Company Inc.",
    "shortName": "comp",
    "salesforceID": "0000",
    "jpower": "00000"
},{
    "fullName": "Company 1 Inc.",
    "shortName": "comp1",
    "salesforceID": "0001",
    "jpower": "00001"
}]
'''

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)
return data.fullName
```

This code returns `[Company Inc., Company 1 Inc.]`

Comment: Thanks the script works, however the parameters not being loaded in the Active choice parameter when i go to the Build With Parameters.

Comment: I am able to return the values to Active choice parameter and populate. 

`import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`

`def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()`

`def data = jsonSlurper.parse(new File('<FileName>'))`

`return data.fullName`